# How to upload folder of text files in ShinyApp to get Document Term Matrix from Corpus of files in R?

Tags: r, shiny, k-means, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I want to upload folder of text files from my system in `Shiny App` to get its `Document Term Matrix` from Corpus to apply `K-means`.
I tried various approach to do this but I am unable to establish connection between all the uploaded files for creating Corpus.
I am able to apply K-means by creating Corpus in Global Environment but I want to do this through ShinyApp by uploading **Folder** or selecting **Multiple Files**.

Below are the codes of what I did so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyFiles)
library(tm)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Document_Clustering"),
  dashboardSidebar( 
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Data Processing", tabName = "DP", icon = icon("info-circle")),
        menuItem("K-Means", tabName = "KMeans", icon = icon("th"))
)),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "DP",
         fluidRow(
          box(fileInput('file1', 'Choose Files',
                       accept=c('text/csv',
                               'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                              '.csv'), multiple = TRUE)
          ,  solidHeader = TRUE))
   ,fluidRow(
    box(title = "Pre-processing",  width = 15 ,tableOutput('proc'))
  )

  ),


  tabItem(tabName = "KMeans",
          fluidRow(
            box(
              title = "Enter Number of Clusters:",
              selectInput("C", choices =c(seq(1 , 15, 1)),label = NULL ,selected = 1), solidHeader = TRUE
            )),
          fluidRow(box(title = "Cluster", width = 9, textOutput("cluster1"))),
          fluidRow(box(title = "Cluster Size", width = 9, textOutput("size1"))),
          fluidRow(box(title= "Between Cluster Hetrogeneity" , width=9, textOutput("hetro1")))

  )
)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)

con<- file(inFile$datapath, open="rt", encoding = "UTF-8")
text<-readLines(con)
msg<- paste(text, collapse = "\n")
close(con)
msg<- msg


myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(msg))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
myCorpus<- tm_map(myCorpus,removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords,stopwords("english"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus,control = list(minWordLength = 1))
dtm_tfxidf <- weightTfIdf(dtm)
m11 <- as.matrix(dtm_tfxidf)
ri <- m11


set.seed(1234)
### Only kmeans
n2 <- input$C
clusk <- kmeans(as.data.frame(ri), n2) #, nstart = 9)

T3<- list(Name= m11, Cluster_K=clusk$cluster, Size_K= clusk$size, Hetro_K=clusk$betweenss/clusk$totss*100)
  })

  output$proc <- renderTable({
    myData()$Name
  })

  output$cluster1 <- renderText({
    myData()$Cluster_K

  })

  output$size1 <- renderText({
    myData()$Size_K

  })

  output$hetro1 <- renderText({
    myData()$Hetro_K
  })

  })

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
```

Using above codes I am able to upload multiple files but I am getting error in its further processing. **Error:invalid 'description' argument** which I am unable to resolve.
Also when I upload only single file then everything seems to work but **I didn't get the reason why the cluster size is 2 in `kmeans` for single file.**

**Any kind of help is much appreciated.**
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot make connection of all the files without using some function and that function was missing from my code.

To make `ShinyApp` work fine, make below changes in **Server part**:

**Replace this**

```
con<- file(inFile$datapath, open="rt", encoding = "UTF-8")
text<-readLines(con)
msg<- paste(text, collapse = "\n")
close(con)
msg<- msg

myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(msg))
```

**With this**

```
    get.msg <- function(path)
{
  con <- file(path, open = "rt", encoding = "latin1")
  text <- readLines(con)
  msg <- text[seq(which(text == "")[1] + 1, length(text), 1)]
  close(con)
  return(paste(msg, collapse = "\n"))
}

data.docs <- inFile$datapath
data.docs <- data.docs[which(data.docs != "cmds")]
all.data <- sapply(data.docs,
                   function(p) get.msg(file.path(p)))

myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(all.data))
```